# edit response json python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

anyway to editing the response in json django? I'm using view.viewset

```
{
  "title": "Cloister",
  "number": 2,
  "summary": "Erasmas describes several buildings of the Concent, namely the Scriptiorium...",
  "page_count": 14
},
```

for example: first I get return in json like this "title": "Cloister", and I want to add something after get string, final result must be: "title": "Cloister+somethinghere"!

my task is get the product name, and check if the name >40 characters then just take 40 character and plus "..." after 40character

Comment: So you want to return the json with a title thats not more than 40 characters. If its more than 3 characters it should and with 3 trailing dots?

Comment: Have you looked at [overriding serialization behavior](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)?

Answer (score 1):

See below:

```
jsonres={
   "title": "Cloister",
   "number": 2,
   "summary": "Erasmas describes several buildings of the Concent, namely the Scriptiorium...",
   "page_count": 14
 }
title=jsonres.get("title")
jsonres["title"]=title + "somethinghere!" #to add something to title
if len(title) > 40:
   jsonres["title"]=title.replace(title[40:],"...") # to truncate 40 + characters and replace
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if characters are less than 40

Comment: @ARR I tried  it wont throw exception condition `if len(title) > 40` wont pass so it simply wont execute the block

Comment: Ah thats true missed it

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I'm using serializer.py and views.py so in serializer I have field like this : fields = ('transaction_id','user_id','status','total','created_at','product'), so how can I edit the response ??, I understand your code, but in my case where can I put it ??

Comment: create a serializer for your model after you serialize the data you will get your response in `serializer.data` you can store it in a variable and make a function of above code and return result of function in `Response` of  `from rest_framework.response import Response` @ViếtPhúTrần